# Get rows where columns are the same value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem with SQL Server. I have table A

```
id  field1  field2  field3
1    a        b       10
2    a        c       20
3    b        e       30
4    b        a       50
5    c        null    20
```

if field1 =10% * field3
if field2 =5% * field3

```
a= 10%*10+10%*20+5%*50=5.5
```

I want to get the table

```
name    values
 a        5.5
 b        8.5
 c         3
 e         1.5
```

please help me . thanks!

Comment: Show what you've tried so far, this is not a difficult query

Comment: I know that but I just learned about sql can you help me?

Comment: Rephrase your question, it's really, really hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Is you want to find different percentages of field3??

Answer (score 0):

I can't understands exactly what you want, but hope you will get idea here.

This is your table (Please post your table structure and inert queries in your questions while posting new questions, so you will get answers quickly and clear to all)

```
create table #temp (id int identity(1,1),field1 varchar(50),field2 varchar(50),field3 int)
INSERT INTO #temp (field1 ,field2 ,field3)
values
('a',        'b' ,    10),
('a',        'c' ,     20),
('b',        'e' ,     30),
('b',        'a' ,     50),
('c',        null ,     20)
```

---

Here is query to select different percentages for all field3 values

```
select field1, 
field2 ,
field3, 
(.1 * field3) as TenPer_field3,
(.05 * field3) as FivePer_field3
from #temp
```

Output:

```
field1  field2  field3  TenPer_field3   Fiveper_field3
a             b   10           1.0       0.50
a             c   20           2.0       1.00
b             e   30           3.0       1.50
b             a   50           5.0       2.50
c          NULL   20           2.0       1.00
```

After you comment i understand what you want.

```
;with CTE AS(
select field1 as name, (.1 * field3) as value from #temp 
Union
select field2 as name, (.05 * field3) as value from #temp 
)
select name,sum(value) value 
from CTE
WHERE name is not null
GROUP BY name
```

output

```
name    value
a         5.50
b         8.50
c         3.00
e         1.50
```

Comment: Thanks. but i want a result query ==> a=5.5 (1.0+2.0+2.5)

Comment: I understand what you want, please check you desired query i edited my answer.

Comment: Great ! That's what I want. Thank Siddique Mahsud very much.

Comment: When someone answer for your question and fullfill what you want, then  please eccept his answer.